# How to extract a sentence containing a certain word without missing periods

Tags: regex

Using RegEx I am trying to extract all sentences from an article containing the word "Figure" and I have this:

```
((?<=^|\s)[A-Za-z0-9][^!?.]*(Figure)[^.]*(?=\.|\!|))
```

which will, in the case of the sentence, "This effect (Smith et al., 2008) was seen in 0.0001% of samples (Figure 1b).", will give me, "of samples (Figure 1b)"

How could I modify my code so it will allow me to capture the decimals and references as well, thereby including the entire sentence from start to end?

Comment: Could you make sure the final match is a period and then a space?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do but I'm not sure how to have it match that specific combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your sentences are well formed (which given they look like they're from a scientific journal they should be) and always start with a capital letter preceded by a space or beginning of string, you can use this regex:

```
(?:^|(?<=[.!?]\s))(?=[A-Z])(?:[^.!?]|[.!?](?!$|\s[A-Z]))*Figure.*?[.!?](?=$|\s[A-Z])
```

This matches:

- `(?:^|(?<=[.!?]\s))` : either start of string or a lookbehind that asserts a `.`,`?`, or `!` followed by a space
- `(?=[A-Z])` : a lookahead asserting a capital letter (we use a lookahead here so we can match `Figure` if it's the first word in the sentence)
- `(?:[^.!?]|[.!?](?!$|\s[A-Z]))*` some number of either a non-sentence ending character or a sentence ending character that is not followed by end-of-string or a space and a capital letter
- `Figure` : the word `Figure`
- `.*?[.!?]` : a minimal number of characters followed by a sentence ending character
- `(?=$|\s[A-Z])` : a lookahead that asserts either end of string or a space and a capital letter (i.e. the start of a new sentence)

[Regex demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8W2cLd/3)